# Activiti candidate group assignment implementation

Tags: java, activiti

I'm trying to assign task to candidate group in Activiti following the next scenario:
User closes his own task and task have to move forward to candidate group.

In Activiti properties this task has no assignees/candidate groups. I'm adding candidate group to this task in java code:

```
public void assignTaskToCandidateGroup(Long entityId) {
    ProcessInstance processInstance = super.findProcessInstance(entity);
    Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(processInstance.getId()).singleResult();
    if (task != null) {
        taskService.complete(task.getId());
    }

    // Get next task after previos closed and add Candidate group
    task = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(processInstance.getId()).singleResult();
    taskService.addCandidateGroup(task.getId(), "candidateGroup");
}

public List<Task> getTaskForCandidateGroup() {
    return taskService.createTaskQuery().taskCandidateGroup("candidateGroup").list();
}

public void claimTaskCandidate(String taskId, User user) {
    Task task = super.findTaskById(taskId);
    List<Task> tasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskCandidateGroup("candidateGroup").list();

    if (!tasks.contains(task))
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("Task with id [%s] is not intended for [%s]",
                task.getId(), "candidateGroup"));

    // ... check services and exception handing omitted

    taskService.claim(task.getId(), user.getUsername());
}
```

I get the following Exception when calling `getTaskForCandidateGroup():`

> "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException",
>
> "message": "Could not write content: lazy loading outside command
>   context (through reference chain:
>   java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity[\"variableInstances\"]);
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: lazy loading
>   outside command context (through reference chain:
>   java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity[\"variableInstances\"])",
>   "path": "/teuis-api/workflow-bps06/getTasksDirectorDeputyGroup"

Can someone suggest another solution to implement this task?

Comment: When do you call getTaskForCandidateGroup() ? Your calling is probably outside of transaction.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I'm calling directly from API (RestController). No additional functionality. Just want to display the tasks with candidate group added. No problem with claiming, the process goes further, but the problem with getting tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved.

I've tried to call the service and return List directly, but it was cause of the error.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTaskForCandidateGroup")
public List<Task> getTaskForCandidateGroup() {
    return getTaskForCandidateGroup();
}
```

New method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getTaskForCandidateGroup")
public List<Map<String, Object>> getTaskForCandidateGroup() {
List<Tasks> taskList = getTaskForCandidateGroup();

List<Map<String, Object>> customTaskList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Task task : taskList) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("taskId", task.getId());
        map.put("taskDefinitionKey", task.getTaskDefinitionKey());
        map.put("taskName", task.getName());

        customTaskList.add(map);
    }
    return customTaskList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a listener associated with the assign event.
Assign is executed before create specifically to handle this scenario.